# How to Get Difference between two datetimes in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime

i have

```
 var hours = sender.get_selectedDate() - LoginTime.get_selectedDate();
 var Hou = parseFloat((hours % 86400000) / 3600000).toFixed(2);
```

I am getting hours = 34200000 
and Hou = 9.50

But i need to get 9 Hours and 30 Minits

how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `9.5` to `9:30` is easy, isn't it? Just use simple math.

```
h=Math.floor(Hou);
m=(Hou-h)*60;
s=h+":"+m // s= '9:30'
```

Comment: Thanks.. but Small change... instead of m=(Hou-h;)*60; i've used m=(Hou-h)*60;

Comment: Oops! I just copied it from Chrome console. Forgot the semicolon :P

Answer (score 0):

use timespan type ..and you can directly add or subtract using its properties.

[click here for timespan](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan)